# Serverless embedded noSQL for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, nosql, embedded-database, document-store

I'm searching for a serverless embedded noSQL document-store database for (mainly) Android  and iOS.
To simplify, I need a document based SQLite :P

MongoDB is great, and has lots of drivers but it needs a server...
Maybe a stripped down version of it could be fine...

Comment: What makes you think that code has anything to do with NoSQL? That looks like a relational ORM to me. Try OrmLite for that. Otherwise, there's a port of TouchDB for Android being worked on.

Comment: Yes, sorry the "example" isn't the best in the world... :(
I've removed it to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with Android, but take a look to this Key/value databases that have been ported (wrapped) to iOS:

- LevelDB (Port: [NULevelDB](https://github.com/nulayer/NULevelDB)): Made by Google, and it seems to be one of the fastest out there.
- TokyoCabinet ( Port: [TSDocDB](https://github.com/isaact/TSDocDB)): Very fast, but it seems to be a bit outdated, the official page states that there's a new version (called KyotoCabinet) that is even faster, but for that there's no port (as far as I know). And, is licensed as LGPL (that it seems not to be fully compatible with the AppStore).

Answer (score 0):

iBoxDB for java can run on Android, it can store objects. if use to store HashMap, it works as document-store database https://github.com/iboxdb/forjava

Answer (score -1):

You should consider Parse.com.  It's very easy to use.  It's not serverless, but they provide the server and it's well worth it.  It's free for small numbers of API requests.

Incidentally, it uses EC2 servers running Ruby and MongoDB and it's incredibly scalable.  It takes almost no work and is on iOS and Android.